# Failed Perlbrew install on shared webspace

Tags: perl, shared-hosting, perlbrew

I am looking for help to install `perlbrew` on my shared webspace (Provider: uberspace.de). I used the usually documentation an `perlbrew.pl` and put:

```
\curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

In my terminal.

Download completed, but than the terminal says:

```
$ curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
103  1247  103  1247    0     0   1274      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1274

## Download the latest perlbrew

## Installing perlbrew
print() on closed filehandle $fh at perlbrew.YQFev9 line 893.
perlbrew is installed: /package/host/localhost/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew
NOTICE: /package/host/localhost/perlbrew/etc/bashrc already exists and not updated.
NOTICE: /package/host/localhost/perlbrew/etc/cshrc already exists and not updated.
Fail to create /package/host/localhost/perlbrew/etc/csh_reinit. Please check the permission of /package/host/localhost/perlbrew/etc and try `perlbrew init` again. at perlbrew.YQFev9 line 806.
```

I have no permission to access `/package/host/localhost/perlbrew/`... 
I think that perlbrew has to install on `/perl5/perlbrew`, right?

How can I change the location of the installation? 
Or is there another problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your hoster already provide perlbrew? What do you get if you run `perlbrew`? What do you get with `perl -v`?